# Intersection points of two polar curves

Tags: multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates

I was asked to find the area inside $r=3cos\theta$ and outside $r=1+cos\theta$ (see figure)

[image]

My question is, how do i find the intersection points, I was taught to make $1+cos\theta = 3cos\theta$ and solving it we get $\theta=\pi/3$ and $\theta =5\pi/3$, but as you can see the curves meet at the pole as well, how do I find this point? (I do not need this for the área but I'm just curious)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find your question interesting.

The trick is that the pole has coordinates $(0,\theta)$, no matter what $\theta$ you choose. So solving $1+\cos\theta = 3\cos \theta$ to find $\theta$ is not necessarily relevant to find this point.

One way of doing it is by asking yourself if for each curve, there is an angle $\theta$ for which $r(\theta)=0$. Clearly it is the case: $\theta_1=\pi/2$ for $r=3\cos\theta$, and $\theta_2 = \pi$ for $r=1+\cos\theta$.

So you have proved that each curve will cross the pole at least once, therefore it is indeed an intersection point of the curves.

Answer (score 0):

Observe one of the points of intersection is given by
\begin{align}
(r\cos\theta, r\sin\theta) 
\end{align}
where $r = 3\cos \frac{\pi}{3}$ and $\theta = \frac{\pi}{3}$.